# loop and insert into another array without redundancy

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to skip inserting repeating same value of array items in my case? I know there is built in function like array unique but my case is different.

Below code produced 12345555555667 but I just want 1234567, means not a value is duplicate.

```
$NumArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');
$SecondArray = array();

foreach($NumArray as $num){
    $SecondArray[] = array(
    'alpa'=>$num
    );
}

echo json_encode($SecondArray);
```

Comment: I believe you've asked a similar question not so long ago.

Comment: What about `$SecondArray[$num] =`...

Comment: how is your case different? Why wouldn't you be able to use `array_unique`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem $numArray's value is not static, it's a loop to construct its array value.

Comment: What about: `foreach(array_unique($NumArray) as $num) {` ?

Comment: @Fernandez: cf my answer, use `$num` as key and use `array_values` before `json_encode` to ensure a json array is returned instead of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new array, then loop the `$NumArray` to check if the value already exists... if not, add it to the new array.

```
<?php
$NumArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');

$newArray = array();
foreach( $NumArray as $val ) {
    if( !in_array( $val, $newArray ) ) {
        $newArray[] = $val;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $newArray );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: so the key thing here is in_array?

Comment: Yes, it checks if the value already is in the array or not. If not, it's added.

Answer (score 1):

If `$NumArray` were static, it's as simple as doing:

```
foreach (array_unique($NumArray) as $num)
{
    //same code as before
}
```

But given that it isn't, you could just write:

```
$SecondArray = ();
foreach ($NumArray as $num)
{
    if (!isset($SecondArray[$num]))
    {//key does not exist (yet)
        $SecondArray[$num] = array('alpa' => $num);
    }
}
echo json_encode(array_values($SecondArray));//remove keys, to ensure a JSON array
```

[see the docs](http://www.php.net/array_values)

The `array_values` call ensures the resulting JSON string is a JS array, and not an object. For example, if `$num` was `1, 2, 3`, the JSON string *without* `array_values` would've looked like this:

```
{
 1: {alpha: 1},
 2: {alpha: 2},
 3: {alpha: 3}
}
```

*With* that call, it looks like this:

```
[
 {alpha: 1},
 {alpha: 2},
 {alpha: 3}
]
```

Comment: what if $num aren't just number but real values like people's name?

Comment: @Fernandez: That doesn't really matter, strings, like numbers, can be used as keys because a PHP array is actually a hash table (sort of like a dictionary in other languages)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$NumArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','6','6','7');
$SecondArray = array();
foreach($NumArray as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($value, $NumArray){
         array_push($SecondArray, $value);
    }
}
echo json_encode($SecondArray);
```

Comment: OP mentions he can't use `array_unique` for some reason (second sentence of the question)

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given on line <b>5</b><br />

Comment: @Fernandez Sorry I missed `$SecondArray = array();`